# VS Code is not showing red squiggly lines beneath errors for Unity C# codes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I am unable to see those red squiggly lines beneath the lines where they are supposed to be. I am using Visual Studio Code with Unity.

Here you can see that it doesn't show a red line even though I did not keep a semicolon(;):

[image: sample image without red lines]

Comment: Are you starting visual studio from within your Unity project while it's open or directly opening the project from Visual Studio?

Comment: First of all, i am using visual studio code, not visual studio, and second, i opened it from unity, not independently.

Comment: I just paid attention to that now. Curious to know why you would want to use visual studio code instead of visual studio for C# programming? Visual studio code is great for many languages and has great tools... but for C# visual studio has always been in the forefront.

Comment: well, if vscode ain't gonna do it, i have no problem in using visual studio!

Comment: Indications to me appear like visual studio code is pushing to make it a better IDE for C# [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/csharp) but I don't think it's at that point yet. Also this speaks about .Net Core development, which Unity is no where close to yet...

Comment: So should i swicth to visual studio?

Comment: i am swithing to visual studio

Answer (score 1):

if you are using C/C++ IntelliSense, then search this in your vs code setting search

```
C_Cpp.errorSquiggles
```

and select **EnabledIfIncludesResolve** in **C_Cpp: Error Squiggles** setting option.

Answer (score 1):

Not in unity, but a standalone C# file I was working on wasn't showing the squiggles. Random text typed in would just be colored like any other variable instead of having a red squiggle underline.

The C# and C# Dev Kit extensions have a line that reads:
"**2. Open a folder/workspace that contains a C# project (.csproj) and a C# solution (.sln) and the extension will activate.**"

Once I created a full project structure the a .NET new console app, I threw my files in that folder and then they were giving the underlining and other syntax tips.

I don't know the structure of Unity projects, and also still don't know how to have the squigglies apply to an individual C# file, but I hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

1. File > Preferences > Settings > type "squiggle" in the search box > set "C_Cpp: Error Squiggles" to enabledIfIncludesResolve or Enable
2. You can go back and forth between "enabledIfIncludesResolve" and "Enable" a few times, to force a change.
3. Restart VS Code
4. You might want to restart OmniSharp, if the lines still do not appear.

Answer (score -1):

Try to do the following :

In vs code :

TOOLS -> Options... -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Disable Squiggles: True/False (Under IntelliSense) -> Click OK

OR

Tools > Options > Text Editor > General > Show error squiggles

OR

TOOLS -> Options... -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced -> Underline Errorsl in the editor

OR

just reset the settings with,
Tools -> Import/Export Setttings -> Reset all settings.

Comment: tools is in visual studio, not in visual studio code, they both are different.

Comment: my mistake it should be visual studio,
In vs code, go to settings and type "show errors" in search and check if the boxes that says "show errors" are checked.